# php foreach loop group in divs

Tags: php, foreach

How i can get this array `$array=array('img1','img2',img3,'img4','img5','img6','img7','img8','img9','img10');` as grouped in divs with foreach loop each group has one parent div

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-3">img1</div>
<div class="col-3">img2</div>
<div class="col-3 d-md-none d-lg-block">img3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4">img4</div>
<div class="col-4">img5</div>
<div class="col-4 d-md-none d-lg-block">img6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-3">img7</div>
<div class="col-3">img8</div>
<div class="col-3 d-md-none d-lg-block">img9</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4">img10</div>
<div class="col-4">img11</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split in chunks:

```
$size = 3;
$array = array('img1','img2',img3,'img4','img5','img6','img7',img8);
$chunks = array_chunk($array, $size);

foreach ($chunks as $ChunkKey => $chunk) {
    // Set class according to current key
    $class = $ChunkKey % 2 ? 'col-4' : 'col-3';?>
<div class="row">
<?php
    $lastKey = count($chunk) - 1;
    // we need key here so as to check whether item is last
    foreach ($chunk as $key => $value) {?>
    <div class="<?=$class?><?= $key === $lastKey ? ' d-md-none d-lg-block' : ''?>">img3</div>
<?php
    }?>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Hi u_mulder, your answer not used 
<div class="col-4">img4</div>